# R DT & blogdown - creating table leads to 'path too long'

Tags: r, datatable, dt, blogdown

I am trying to create a table with the DT package in my blogdown post.
However, datatable(mydata) leads to `Error in dirname(to) : path too long`. The path has 71 characters. The full trace back of the error is

```
Error in dirname(to) : path too long
12.
dirname(to)
11.
dir.exists(x)
10.
utils::file_test("-d", paths)
9.
dir_exists(dirname(to))
8.
(function (from, to, isdir) { if (!dir_exists(dirname(to))) dir.create(dirname(to), recursive = TRUE) ...
7.
mapply(function(from, to, isdir) { if (!dir_exists(dirname(to))) dir.create(dirname(to), recursive = TRUE) if (isdir && !dir_exists(to)) ...
6.
copyDependencyToDir(dep, libdir, FALSE)
5.
FUN(X[[i]], ...)
4.
lapply(rendered$dependencies, function(dep) { dep <- copyDependencyToDir(dep, libdir, FALSE) dep <- makeDependencyRelative(dep, dir, FALSE) dep ...
3.
htmltools::save_html(htmlProduct, file = htmlfile, libdir = libraryFolder)
2.
print.htmlwidget(x)
1.
(function (x, ...) UseMethod("print"))(x)
```

I don't think that the problem is indeed the length of the path, since I do not encounter this error when using the datatable function outside of blogdown. Any idea? The same error also occurs when I use the `reactable` package.

Comment: Possibly changing the working directory to the desktop would be worth a short and try. `setwd(shorterExistingWorkDir)`

Comment: @DanielJachetta thanks! I  copied the entire folder to e.g. my desktop and indeed, the error disappears. It's still somewhat puzzling to me since the original path had 'only' around 80 characters. The blog is an R-Project and I use the here package to account for the working directory... Re-locating the entire folder is however not really an appealing solution...

Comment: I understand, that’s just a solution that I found. I thought I saw that the file paths could handle up to ~200 characters so you’re a shouldn’t be a problem. I know about the here package, but haven’t used it so can’t give suggestions on that

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem while working with DT in R markdown. Indeed the path to the R markdown file that I was running was too long.

Simply shortening the name of the file and moving it to a location on my computer with a shorter path solved the problem.